# What are the Benifit/Advantage of c#/VB.net Property Properties - Private access modifiers for Setters 

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, c#-4.0, properties

Below is the class with a property.

```
public class abc
    {
        public int MyProperty { get; private set; }
    }
```

Confusion - What's the benefit of typing private access modifier in setter ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The private setter allows the property to only be set internally to the class, while the getter still exposes the property value publicly.

Answer (score 6):

Simply, it's a property that the class itself is allowed to set, but external objects can only read. Perhaps `MyProperty` changes as a side effect to a method, perhaps it is only set once (in a constructor). The main point is the source of change with `MyProperty` has to come from within `abc` (or a nested class of `abc`), not from something outside that holds a reference to it.

As for why you might use it, perhaps outside code cannot be trusted to set this value. The class isn't strictly *immutable*, it *can* change, but the only code trusted to do it exists inside the class (or a nested class). The outside world can simply read.

Answer (score 2):

The private modifier allows the property to be read-only in the context of public, protected, or internal access, while giving the type itself the ability to set the property (i.e., in the context of private access).

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple reasons to use private set.

1) If you are not using a backing field at all and want a read-only automatic property:

```
public class abc
    {
        public int MyProperty { get; private set; }
    }
```

2) If you want to do extra work when you modify the variable inside your class and want to capture that in a single location:

```
private string _name = string.Empty;
public string Name 
{ 
    get { return _name; }
    private set 
    {
        TextInfo txtInfo = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TextInfo;
        _name = txtInfo.ToTitleCase(value);
    }
}
```

In general, though, it's a matter of personal preference. Far as I know, there are no performance reasons to use one over the other.

Answer (score 1):

This is done to make your property read-only so that the external world is not allowed to change the value of the property and only the class implementing the property can change the property value being the owner of the property.
As an example of how a class tracks its instance count and the instance count only can be increased/decreased from inside the class and the external world should not be allowed to change the instance count property e.g.:

```
public class Customer
{    
    public Customer()
    {
        InstanceCount++;
    }

    //Helps retrieving the total number of Customers
    public int InstanceCount { get; private set; } //Count should not be increased by the clients of this class rather should be increased in the constructor only
}
```

Another benefit in some situations is, after giving a private set to your property you can give a Set method for changing the property value from external world when you want to do some calculations or validations on the value received (which is not a best practice to do inside the Set property accessors), and then change the value of the property as follows:

```
public class Customer
{
    public string City { get; private set; }

    public bool SetCity(string customerCity)
    {
        //validate that the customerCity is a valid USA city or else throw some business rule exception, and then call below code
        City = customerCity
    }
}
```